BAT script not returning Latest link from the text file
I was trying to get the latest
<a href> 

link i.e 122 from  below temp.txt file
<html>
<head><meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="100/">100/</a>                                     23-Mar-2022 17:12    -
<a href="111/">111/</a>                                     21-Mar-2023 12:08    -
<a href="112/">112/</a>                                     18-Apr-2023 07:46    -
<a href="113/">113/</a>                                     25-May-2023 21:15    -
----
                                   
<a href="120/">120/</a>                                     11-Dec-2023 10:43    -
<a href="121/">121/</a>                                     30-Jan-2024 07:31    -
**<a href="122/">122/</a>                                     11-Mar-2024 06:00    -**
<a href="93/">93/</a>                                      24-Aug-2021 16:07    -
<a href="94/">94/</a>                                      12-Oct-2021 11:21    -
<a href="95/">95/</a>                                      26-Oct-2021 16:25    -
<a href="97/">97/</a>                                      06-Jan-2022 15:23    -
<a href="98/">98/</a>                                      07-Feb-2022 16:04    -
<a href="99/">99/</a>                                      10-Mar-2022 12:18    -
<a href="json/">json/</a>                                    03-Apr-2024 04:26    -
<a href="linux/">linux/</a>                                   17-Jun-2020 12:06    -
<a href="known-good-version-with-downloads.json">known-good-version-with-downloads.json</a>   01-Apr-2024 07:03  1.39 KB
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/7.49.12 Server at artifactrepository.xxxxxx.net Port 80</address></body></html>

I have used below batch script
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "latestHref="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type temp.txt ^| findstr /i "href="') do (
    set "href=%%a"
    set "href=!href:*href=!"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("!href!") do (
        set "latestHref=%%~b"
    )
)

if defined latestHref (
    echo Latest href link: !latestHref!
) else (
    echo No href links found in the text file.
)

but every time i am getting No href links found in the text file can someone help me pls
I was expecting 122 in the result , but still getting wrong result

in your inner for loop, the string starts with a =. There is nothing before, so the FIRST token is the thing after the =, not the second one. May I suggest to replace your inner  loop with for /f tokens^=2delims^=^" %%b in ("!href!") do set "latestHref=%%~b" (get the second token delimited by " (which needs this strange syntax to work correctly with " as delimter`) - this gets you the string between the quotes.

This gets you the string known-good-version-with-downloads.json, from the last <a href line. That's clearly not 122. How to determine this number? Highest number or latest date? You need some more logic  to locate the correct line (as there clearly is no reliable sorting in the file)

Filter for the <a href="NUMBERS lines and adapt the !latestHref! if the found number is bigger than before (use adapted delimiters):
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "latestHref="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type temp.txt ^| findstr /i "href=\"[0-9][0-9]*') do (
    set "href=%%a"
    set "href=!href:*href=!"
    for /f tokens^=2delims^=/^" %%b in ("!href!") do (
        if %%b gtr !latestHref! set "latestHref=%%~b"
    )
)

if defined latestHref (
    echo Latest href link: !latestHref!
) else (
    echo No href links found in the text file.
)

output:
Latest href link: 122


If you have not modified your example text file content in a way that would prompt incorrect solutions, something like this should work for you:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "NumLnk=0" & For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=/^"^ EOL^= %%G In ('2^>NUL
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"<a href=\"[123456789][0123456789]*/"
 "P:\athTo\temp.txt"') Do If %%G Gtr !NumLnk! Set "NumLnk=%%G"
If %NumLnk% Equ 0 Echo No href links found in the text file.& Pause & Exit /B
Echo Latest href link: %NumLnk%
Pause

Notes:

You will need to change P:\athTo\temp.txt to your own absolute or relative file path and name. Please do not choose to use a filename only.
The last line Pause is optional, (included only for your testing), so you can remove or overwrite it should you wish.

